# LeetCode 1011. Binary Search, C++ and Python same idea but different outputs

Tags: c++

Can anybody take a look at my CPP code?
It's from this problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/capacity-to-ship-packages-within-d-days/
I feel very frustrated cuz though my python code works, my cpp code doesn't work as always. :pensive: Same idea, different results. It drives me crazy.

The correct output should be `15`.
My Python code returns the right output `15` while my CPP code returns the wrong output `10`.

My python code:

```py
def cnt_days(weights, k):
        total, cnt = 0, 1
        for w in weights:
            if total + w > k:
                total = 0
                cnt += 1
            total += w
        print(total, cnt)
        return cnt

def shipWithinDays(weights, D):
    left = max(weights)
    right = max(weights) * len(weights) // D + 1

    while left < right:
        mid = left + (right - left) // 2
        if cnt_days(weights, mid) > D:
            left = mid + 1
        else:
            right = mid
    return left           


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(shipWithinDays([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 5))
```

My cpp code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int cnt_days(vector<int>& weights, int K)
{
    int total = 0, cnt = 1;
    for (int w: weights)
    {
        if (total + w > K) 
        {
            total = 0;
            cnt++;
        }
        else total += w;
    }
    cout << total <<" "<<  cnt << endl;
    return cnt;
}

int shipWithinDays(vector<int>& weights, int D)
{
    int maximum = *max_element(weights.begin(), weights.end());
    int left = maximum;
    int right = maximum * weights.size() / D + 1;
    while (left < right)
    {
        int mid = left + (right - left)/2;
        if (cnt_days(weights, mid) > D)
            left = mid + 1;
        else
            right = mid;
    }
    return left;    
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> weights = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int D = 5;
    cout << shipWithinDays(weights, D) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you run both codes under debugger and compare them step by step?

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for the comment!
I'll have to learn how to debug in my VScode. I've encountered a problem.
It says it's "Unable to start debugging. The value of miDebuggerPath is invalid."
I'll have to do some research to figure out why.

Comment: You can also insert `std::cout / print` statements inside `while` and compare the outputs.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's a great method. Let me have a try. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your C++ `cnt_days` has an "else" that's not in the Python version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the else

```
else total += w;
```

should be

```
total += w;
```

Comment: Please provide more detail for further information.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, you could binary search much simple for your [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) solution:

```
#include <vector>

class Solution {
public:
    int shipWithinDays(std::vector<int>& weights, int d) {
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = INT_MAX;

        for (int weight : weights) {
            lo = max(lo, weight);
        }

        while (lo < hi) {
            int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
            int required = 1;
            int cur = 0;

            for (int index = 0; index < weights.size() && required <= d; cur += weights[index++])
                if (cur + weights[index] > mid) {
                    cur = 0;
                    required++;
                }


            if (required > d) {
                lo = mid + 1;

            } else {
                hi = mid;
            }

        }

        return lo;
    }
};
```

Or with basic bitwise operations:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int shipWithinDays(vector<int> &weights, int d) {
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = INT_MAX;

        for (int weight : weights)
            lo = max(lo, weight);

        while (lo < hi) {
            int mid = lo + ((hi - lo) >> 1);
            int required = 1;
            int cur = 0;

            for (int index = 0; index < weights.size() && required <= d; cur += weights[index++])
                if (cur + weights[index] > mid)
                    cur = 0, required++;

            if (required > d)
                lo = -~mid;

            else
                hi = mid;

        }

        return lo;
    }
};
```

---

Similarly for python:

```
from typing import List

class Solution:
    def shipWithinDays(self, weights: List[int], d: int) -> int:
        lo, hi = max(weights), sum(weights)
        while lo < hi:
            mid = lo + ((hi - lo) >> 1) # or mid = (lo + hi) // 2 || mid = lo + (hi - lo) // 2
            cur, required = 0, 1
            for weight in weights:
                if cur + weight > mid:
                    required += 1
                    cur = 0
                cur += weight
            if required > d:
                lo = -~mid # simply lo = mid + 1
            else:
                hi = mid

        return lo
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/capacity-to-ship-packages-within-d-days/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions, explanations, efficient algorithms with a variety of languages, and time/space complexity analysis in there.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for typing so many words! Very good and useful advice. Very helpful!